# Windows 10 - WinAPI - detect if power button pressed

Tags: winapi, power-management

Is it possible to detect if a hardware power button has been pressed on tablet (only for the state transition "Power ON" -> "Power off/suspend")?

I don't need to handle it anyhow - just log if it happened.

I'm aware about WM_POWERBROADCAST approach, but it's not possible to determine if power status changed with hardware button or somehow else.

Comment: The Windows API does not let you detect *WHY* the power state is changing, only that the state *IS* changing.  Why do you need to differentiate between the physical Power button versus the Power menu?

Comment: Probably It needs some kernel tricks to determine what raised a power state change. Or you can hook into other programs to interpret shutdown API calls.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this is kind of "kiosk" environment but user can still press hardware power button, power menu and any other Windows UI are not accessible for the user. For now I just want to log if power button was pressed.